# Why does std::istream::ignore discard characters?

Tags: c++, istream

On the [CPlusPlus website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) for `std::istream::ignore`, it says

> `istream& ignore (streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF);`
>
> **Extract and discard characters**
>
> Extracts characters from the input
>   sequence and discards them, until either n characters have been
>   extracted, or one compares equal to delim.

Why does it say it **discards them** rather than **returns them**?

**EDIT**

As requested, here is the particular code in question. It is a callback function, server-side, processing the client file that was sent (`_data`)

```
static void loadFile (const std::string &_fileName, std::vector<char> &_data)                                                                                            
{
    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
    ifs.open(_fileName, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
    auto startPos = ifs.tellg();
    ifs.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
    auto size = static_cast<std::size_t>(ifs.gcount());
    ifs.seekg(startPos);
    _data.resize(size);
    ifs.read(_data.data(), size);
    std::cout << "loaded " << size << " bytes" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: because "returns" would be wrong. It returns the `istream` not the characters

Comment: I don't think I understand the question... It **discards** them, in the sense that they are **thrown away**, you don't get to see or use them in any code you write.

Comment: agree that the question is a bit unclear. Maybe you can explain why you think "returns them" would be more appropriate

Comment: That's even part of the function *name*, to *ignore* things.

Comment: @user463035818 I want to read the contents of a file (`std::ifstream ifs`, `ifs.open(...)`) then I want to read it (`ifs.read(...)`). I am reviewing someone else's code and they have a `ifs.ignore(std::numeric_limits...)` in there. I assumed it was just telling the compiler to read the whole file. So my question is why is it "discarding" anything

Comment: It's a common way to read the beginning of a line, and then *ignore* (and discard) the rest of the line. It makes sense with text files when using formatted input (the `>>` operator) but not for general "binary" files or when using `read` to read larger blocks. Without more context we can only guess badly, and even with context we can still only guess. The only person that can reliably answer your question is the one who wrote the code.

Comment: @puk - You should probably show a snippet of code to provide some context. Maybe the file is a set of records with formatting, so you can safely skip (read and discard) sequences of characters. But the immediate answer to the question is, there is no way to return them, so they get discarded after being read.

Comment: @jww Will modify the question shortly

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude to me, a non expert, it seems rather strange to specify that it discards something just because it doesn't return. Like saying ping discards the website content because it doesn't return it, or a tax audits discards the entire corporation.

Comment: What the `ignore` call in the code snippet you show does, is to find out the number of bytes in the file. The `ignore` reads (and discards) the whole file, updating the value returned by `gcount`. This value is used to preallocate the vector that stores the data, and then the whole file is read into the vector in a single `read` call.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understand now, you need to *dummy read* it so you know the size, so you can resize the target (`data`) so you can read it for real

Comment: Correct. The reason `ignore` is used is because [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) does not update the counters, so you can't just seek to the end and get the size but have to actually read the whole file. And since it's hard to read the whole file without knowing the size (it's a catch-22) and there is a function which *can* do that and also discard the irrelevant data at the same time the author just uses that funciton: `ignore`.

Comment: I think this question has the potential to be a good one if you reformulate it to ask about the use of `ignore` in the snippet you posted (rather than why a function named `ignore`, well, ignores the input).

Comment: Agree with @T.C. Its not a bad question. The presentation has room for improvement. It is probably a lot easier to do now that you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto startPos = ifs.tellg();
```

This stores the position at the beginning of the (just-opened) file.

```
ifs.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
```

This reads through the entire file (until EOF) and discards the content read.

```
auto size = static_cast<std::size_t>(ifs.gcount());
```

`gcount` returns the number of characters read by the last unformatted input operation, in this case, the `ignore`. Since the `ignore` read every character in the file, this is the number of characters in the file.

```
ifs.seekg(startPos);
```

This repositions the stream back to the beginning of the file,

```
_data.resize(size);
```

...allocates enough space to store the entire file's content,

```
ifs.read(_data.data(), size);
```

and finally reads it again into `_data`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it say it discards them rather than returns them?

Because there are other functions to return them. See [`std::istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) 
 and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

---

**Update**

The whole purpose of the following lines in your updated post is to obtain the size of the file.

```
auto startPos = ifs.tellg();
ifs.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
auto size = static_cast<std::size_t>(ifs.gcount());
```

This is the first time I have seen use of `istream::ignore()` to do that. You could also use the following to get the size of the file.

```
// Find the end of the file
ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::end);

// Get its position. The returned value is the size of the file.
auto size = ifs.tellg();
```

Comment: Then would a line like `ifs.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());` do nothing?

Comment: @puk, it would do something. It would read the characters and discard them. That is not doing nothing.

Comment: At most `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` chars. (which is a lot!) This may be an **XY Problem** -- why are you discarding them to begin with?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin its not "at least" but "at most" ;)

Comment: @user463035818 -- good eye. It was somewhat a lackadaisical comment to begin with, but you are correct.

Comment: Actually, it would discard all of them, regardless of the size of the file. `istream::ignore` treats `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` as a special value that means ignore the whole stream (up until the specified delimiter).

Comment: If you do `ifs.open()...ifs.seekg(ifs.tellg())...ifs.read()` what purpose does `ignore` serve?

Comment: @puk, `ignore` can be used to ignore only up to a delimiter. `ignore(size, '\n')` is probably the most often used scenario.

Comment: @RSahu I fully understand, which makes it all the more difficult for me to understand why the author chose to do this. I will expand on the question shortly